# How to use generics with a slice of struct correctly?

Tags: go

I'm working on a project. This is my first time of using generics in Go in a project. So far, for the function and the code itself, it works fine. But, I encountered a problem when I'm trying to create a unit test that uses struct for test tables.

This is the type definition & the function I wanna test.

```golang
type AllowedTypes interface {
  int | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | float32 | float64 | string
}

func LinearSearch[T AllowedTypes](value T, array []T){
    for _, e := range array {
        if e == value {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

That code above works fine. But, when I'm trying to create the

```golang
func TestLinearSearch(t *testing.T) {
    type tableProps[T AllowedTypes] struct {
        Name           string
        Value          T
        Array          []T
        ExpectedResult bool
    }

    tables := []tableProps{
        {
            Name:           "Success: Value Exists (int)",
            Value:          5,
            Array:          []interface{}{1, 3, 5, 6, 8},
            ExpectedResult: true,
        },
        {
            Name:           "Success: Value Exists (string)",
            Value:          "y",
            Array:          []interface{}{"a", "c", "f", "g", "y"},
            ExpectedResult: true,
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range tables {
        t.Run(tt.Name, func(t *testing.T) {
            actualResult := LinearSearch(tc.Value, tc.Array)

            require.Equal(t, tc.ExpectedResult, actualResult)
        })
    }
}
```

The code above itself throws this error

```bash
cannot use generic type tableProps[T AllowedTypes] without instantiation
```

So, I assumed that I have to instantiate the generic type into the struct object. So, I changed the code to be something like this

```golang
func TestLinearSearch(t *testing.T) {
    type tableProps[T AllowedTypes] struct {
        Name           string
        Value          T
        Array          []T
        ExpectedResult bool
    }

    tables := []tableProps[AllowedTypes]{
        {
            Name:           "Success: Value Exists (int)",
            Value:          5,
            Array:          []AllowedTypes{1, 3, 5, 6, 8},
            ExpectedResult: true,
        },
        {
            Name:           "Success: Value Exists (string)",
            Value:          "y",
            Array:          []AllowedTypes{"a", "c", "f", "g", "y"},
            ExpectedResult: true,
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range tables {
        t.Run(tt.Name, func(t *testing.T) {
            actualResult := LinearSearch(tc.Value, tc.Array)

            require.Equal(t, tc.ExpectedResult, actualResult)
        })
    }
}
```

This one also doesn't work. But it throws a different error message:

```bash
cannot use type AllowedTypes outside a type constraint: interface contains type constraints
```

So, how am I supposed to use the custom generics into a slice of structs like on my case above?

I've googled the solutions but the only things I found is to tell me that I need to istantiate it using the generic type like this.

```golang
    tables := []tableProps[int]{
        {
            Name:           "Success: Value Exists (int)",
            Value:          5,
            Array:          []int{1, 3, 5, 6, 8},
            ExpectedResult: true,
        },
    }
```

I tried it and it works (for the first the case). But, if I use this solution, it means the data type for `Value` and `Array` field needs to be `int` and `[]int` respectively which as you can see it won't be appropriate for my case because I'm gonna use lots of other data types (under AllowedTypes) for other cases simulataneously.

Comment: you can't have a slice of different instantiations of a generic type. the only way is `[]any`

Comment: also consider that it doesn't make a lot of sense to test the function for each possible type in its constraint. You wrote the function to be **generic**. If it compiles in the first place, it will behave the same for any type argument, as long as the operators have the same semantics (in your case `==` does)